# WIX: Restart service if Setup is cancelled?

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer, install-sequence

Is it possible to restart a service if setup MSI is cancelled by the user?

There is two scenarios where the MSI has to restart the service.

1. Stop and update the old service files and then start the service. If service fails to start, replace back the old files and restart the service. [This part is done with rollback]
2. Restart the service if MSI is **cancelled** intentionally during setup process.

I have a solution that I can call a `CustomAction` on cancel and used CMD.EXE to restart a service, but I don't like it. Please suggest any other solution like by using `RestartResource` or `ResourceManager`

Code:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence >
    <RemoveExistingProducts
      After="InstallInitialize"/>
    <Custom Action="RenameFileOnCancel" OnExit="cancel">1</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>

 <CustomAction
        Id='RestartService'
        Directory='TARGETDIR'
        ExeCommand='[SystemFolder]cmd.exe net stop AppServerSvc &amp;&amp; net start AppServerSvc'
        Return='asyncWait'
        Execute='deferred'
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you schedule the upgrade MSI during the transaction, for example use:

- `MajorUpgrade/@Schedule='afterInstallInitialize'` or
- `MajorUpgrade/@Schedule='afterInstallExecute'` or
- `MajorUpgrade/@Schedule='afterInstallExecuteAgain'`

**and** use the `ServiceControl` element to start/stop/restart the service then the Windows Installer will do all the work for you.

This is *by far* the most recommended way to accomplish your goal.